# Why does Perl's DateTime::Astro::Sunrise give me unexpected values?

Tags: perl

Using the example code included in the man page for [DateTime::Astro::Sunrise](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime::Astro::Sunrise), I'm getting back ~14:00 for the sunrise and ~2:00 for the sunset.

My machine's time and timezone are set correctly (AFAIK).

Am I reading something wrong? 2am and 2pm are just so brutually wrong.

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Astro::Sunrise;

my $dt = DateTime->new( year   => 2010,
                                month  => 3,
                                day    => 15,
                         );
my $sunrise = DateTime::Astro::Sunrise ->new('-117','33',undef,1);

my ($tmp_rise, $tmp_set) = $sunrise->sunrise($dt);

printf "%s\n", $tmp_rise;
printf "%s\n", $tmp_set;
```

Comment: A few more details are required. What's your latitude, longitude, date and timezone...?

Comment: Are you doing something wrong? Maybe. How can we tell without seeing what you're doing? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, without any sample code, I can't say what you are doing wrong.

An alternative, [Astro::Sunrise](http://search.cpan.org/~rkhill/Astro-Sunrise-0.91/Sunrise.pm) has been working well for me, and appears to be slightly more mature.

Comment: nice.... same author of the two modules.  Complete success after switching to the Astro::Sunrise

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, you've got the wrong sign on your longitude, so you're getting the sunrise/sunset times for Shanghai (which are about 6AM and 6PM Shanghai time right now), but you're getting the times *in California time* that the sun rises and sets in Shanghai, since that's your local timezone. Difference is 16 hours, so you get 2PM and 2AM.